# Exception calling "Invoke" with "2" argument(s): "Number of parameters specified does not match the expected number

Tags: command-line, powershell

Hi guys im not sure why my code does not work properly on adding a user from remote desktop users but it works perfectly fine at Administrators group below is my code

```
$serversList ="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.csv"

$servers= Import-Csv -Path $serversList `
                      -Delimiter "," `
                      -Header ComputerNM,UserGroup,Domain

foreach($Computer in $servers) 

{

$Status=$null
$Comment = $null
$ComputerName= $Computer.ComputerNM
$Usrgroup = $Computer.UserGroup  #"Here we get username"
$ObjName = $Computer.UserGroup
$Domain     = $Computer.Domain
$count++


if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName -Count 1 -Quiet) 

{
   
    Write-Output "$ComputerName : Online"
     try {
               #$Domain     = $env:userdomain

               $GroupObj = [ADSI]('WinNT://'+$ComputerName+'/"Remote Desktop users",group') 
               $GroupObj.psbase.Invoke('Add',([ADSI]"WinNT://$Domain/$ObjName").path)
            $Status = "Success"
            $Comment = "Added $ObjName $ObjectType to Local administrators group on [$ComputerName]"
            Write-Output "Successfully added $ObjName $ObjectType to $ComputerName"
        }
        catch {
              $Status = "Failed"
               $Comment = $ObjectType  + "[$ObjName] - " + $_.toString().replace("`n","").replace("`r","")
              Write-Output "Failed to add $ObjName $ObjectType to $ComputerName"
          }
          $ResultsFile = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\t1.txt"

         Add-Content -Path $ResultsFile -Value ("{0},{1},{2}" -f $ComputerName,$Status,$Comment )
           
}

}
```

here's my were i tried adding it manually on administrators and remote desktop users
as you can see here same scenario where if i add a users at remote desktop users i encounter an error "Exception calling "Invoke" with "2" argument(s): "Number of parameters specified does not match the expected number"

```
C:\Windows\system32>powershell -c "Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member "domain\account""

C:\Windows\system32>powershell -c "Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Remote Desktop Users" -Member "domain\account""
Add-LocalGroupMember : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Desktop'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-LocalGroupMember -Group Remote Desktop Users -Member domain\account ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-LocalGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddLocalGroupMemberCommand
```

Comment: You have double quotes inside a double quoted string. I don't know if powershell is OK with single quotes, or if you need to escape the interior double quotes.

Comment: i have tried that single qoute or double qoute same issue

Comment: @VidaVida Use `powershell -c 'Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Remote Desktop Users" -Member "domain\account"'` .... Give it a shot. Use single quotes around the entire command after `-c` then use double quotes around the quoted values within the command. Happy Learning!!

Comment: will do thank you ill give you an update later once my shift is started
how about my main code thou should i use single quotation

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle its working thou but how should i applied that in my original code? this one $GroupObj = [ADSI]('WinNT://'+$ComputerName+'/"Remote Desktop users",group')

Comment: okok will do that now ill give you an update in a few mins

Comment: still encountered - Exception calling "Invoke" with "2" argument(s): "Number of parameters specified does not match the expected number."

Comment: Hi @VidaVida Can you add sample masked out sensitive with generic data csv file examples. Just like in the format you have. Can you explain what it is you are trying to accomplish for the ultimate goal, just adding csv domain user or local users account, on csv computer listed domain joined computer, to add that user to that local or domain security group? Minus all the logging, are you just trying to take objects from each row in the csv and run specific actions on those items per line values? I wonder if you have a null csv data like `data,,` or if you have wrong `[ADSI]` syntax.

Comment: If you can explain what you are trying to do on each listed computer, etc. I can probably help you with a way I know to achieve the same result. I see this post from 2008 that lists some of those `[ADSI]` ways in case it helps clarify syntax or if that's applicable in your environment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-add-a-domain-user-to-a-local-group/ Look here too: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/82a01568-1dd4-4505-bf6f-b79cc51da39f/adsi-script-not-working-for-remote-pcs?forum=ITCG

Comment: my code purpose is to add a user on a specific group on multiple server's
below is a sample format of my csv

IP Address,Useraccount,Domain